# SharpGL turn of SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl.timer_Tick

Tags: c#, wpf, opengl, sharpgl

Currently I'm working with SharpGL and WPF, to test wheter its performence is decent. The test is to load a large STL-file ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format) ) and to draw it on the SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl and rotate, scale, transform it. The current result is, that it's not decent, but that might be because it is continously calling my Paint()-method which in turn is called from a method SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl.timer_Tick.

Question: How to turn of this time_Tick ? (Each call to time_Tick costs 67 milliseconds because I draw in immediate mode. )